# Error viewing Accounts tab in User view

Tags: bug, status-completed, 500-server-error, user-accounts

When I click on the Accounts tab when viewing my profile I get the screen with the title:
(To clarify, this occurs both on stackoverflow and meta)

> "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

It is continuing to happen. 
This is the first time I have visited meta and have an account on stackoverflow and serverfault.

Not sure if anyone can help me at this time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chacha102 has noted, this was **our fault**.

The bug has been fixed - sorry for the troubles!

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the error:

> It's not you, it's us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified

It is **NOT YOU**, it is an error on the developers side of the site.

Give it a few days/hour/however-fast-they-can-type, and it will be fixed.

Comment: I can't type very fast :)